# Bash to check if directory exist. If not create with an array

Tags: bash, directory, array

I want to write a Bash script, which checks if all directories, stored in an array, exist. If not, the script should create it. Is this a correct way to do it?

```
array1=(
/apache
/apache/bin
/apache/conf
/apache/lib
/www
/www/html
/www/cgi-bin
/www/ftp
)
if [ ! -d “$array1” ]; then
  mkdir $array1
else 
  break
fi
```

Comment: Are those `”` actually intended to be `"`?  The difference is important!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to loop in your array, then I would propose, in bash

```
array1=(
/apache
/apache/bin
/apache/conf
/apache/lib
/www
/www/html
/www/cgi-bin
/www/ftp
)
for dir in "${array1[@]}"; do
  [[ ! -d "$dir" ]] && mkdir "$dir"
done
```

Comment: @user3573614 For further understanding: `bash` arrays start at index 0 by default. If an array is called without specifying an element (or range of elements), it will default to the element with index 0, i.e. `${array}` is the same as `${array[0]}`

Comment: You may want to use `mkdir -p` to create all subdirectories at once.

Answer (score 54):

Just use:

```
mkdir -p -- "${array1[@]}"
```

That will also create intermediary directory components if need be so your array can also be shortened to only include the leaf directories:

```
array1=(
  /apache/bin
  /apache/conf
  /apache/lib
  /www/html
  /www/cgi-bin
  /www/ftp
)
```

Which you could also write:

```
array1=(
  /apache/{bin,conf,lib}
  /www/{html,cgi-bin,ftp}
)
```

The `[[ -d ... ]] || mkdir ...` type of approaches in general introduce [TOCTOU race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) and are better avoided wherever possible (though in this particular case it's unlikely to be a problem).

Comment: Or only use a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) without an array: `mkdir -p /apache/{bin,conf,lib} /www/{html,cgi-bin,ftp}`

Comment: About TOCTOU: (1) If the directory doesn't exist when checked, mkdir will be executed with both this answer and the check-create sequence. In both cases the end result is that the directory exists for code to be executed on following lines. (2) If the directory exists when checked and gets erased (by some other entity) the directory ends up not existing for the code on next lines. The same effect happens if the directory is created with mkdir directly and then it gets erased (by some other entity) anyway. (3) if either (1) or (2) are deemed to be problem,  they are in both type of answers.

Comment: The real problem is to have more than **one** entity changing the directory (without proper semaphores). As very few disk operations are truly atomic, most disk operations will fall into some type of race.

Comment: Granted, not making the check is less code to execute.

Comment: @Isaac, the general principal is that it's better to do _try to make it true and ignore the error that says it was already true_ (EAFP at the wikipedia page, like `mkdir -p` does), than _check if true and make it true if not_ (LBYL) which fails (`mkdir` without `-p` returning with an error) if something has made it true in between the *check* and *make*, like here if two instances of the script are run at the same time. As I said, unlikely to be a problem here, and you could even say it's probably better to exit early if the script is already running.

Comment: (1) @StéphaneChazelas The basic and underlying principle in **shell programing** is that it is **impossible** to avoid race conditions no matter how hard you try if two entities could access the same resource (with same level permissions). No matter which solution you choose to adopt (either `mkdir` or `mkdir -p`) the **next** command will have no guarantee about the directory. In fact, even at a lower level, from the Wikipedia article: *In 2004, an impossibility result was published, showing that there was no portable, deterministic technique for avoiding TOCTOU race conditions.*

Comment: (2) In a shell script the race conditions could not be removed. It is therefore **useless** to raise TOCTOU as a reason to use or avoid the use of some kind of code or other. A  TOCTOU will always be possible between two consecutive commands.

Comment: (3) The only safe way to avoid TOCTOU is to follow the sequence lock-check-use-unlock including in **use** all commands that need access to the resource. And assuming that the lock is done by a higher level entity. Or, at minimum, that all entities coordinate the use of the resource. Of course, that last requirement can't hold for an adversary. The shell doesn't provide, nor it even tries to provide such assurances unless you build additional protections.

Comment: (4) Your answer here does provide a shorter solution which is reasonably better, granted. That is enough to make it a "good answer".

Answer (score 1):

I would like to expand on the answer provided by @darxmurf.

For those that are just learning Linux or shell scripting, I want to point out that
`mkdir /path1/path2/path3` may not do exactly what you want.
I would suggest adding `chown`, `chmod`, and `sort` to the script.

If `/path1/path2` does not exist, `mkdir /path1/path2/path3` will fail.
This can be somewhat corrected by
`mkdir -p /path1/path2/path3`

In this case, all 3 paths will be created with the UID, GID & UMASK of the user running the command. If the user's UMASK is 077, you could end up with:
`mkdir -m 777 -p /path1/path2/path3`
your directories will then look like this:

```
drwx------ /path1
drwx------ /path2
drwxrwxrwx /path3
```

Which is not what you want.

Using `sort` will order the shorter paths first. Consider an array of:
`/apache/bin/cache /apache /apache/bin`
Really, you'd want the array to be:
`/apache /apache/bin /apache/bin/cache`

My first suggested change would be:

```
array=(
/apache
/apache/bin
/apache/conf
/apache/lib
/www
/www/html
/www/cgi-bin
/www/ftp
)
array1=$( echo "${array[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort )
```

This will guarantee the higher level directories will show up before the lower levels.

The next change I would make is the `-m` for mode. This will ensure the permissions you want are set on the directory:
`mkdir -m ${mode} ${dir}`

Setting the owner & group (esp if running as root). If you are a member of GroupA and GroupB, the mkdir command will set the group owner to your default group (the first group that shows on an `id` command). Thus:
`[[ ! -d "$dir" ]] && mkdir -m ${mode} "$dir" && chown ${user}:${group} "${dir}"`

Comment: In your example `array1` is not array and paths containing space characters, tabs or newlines would cause undesired results.

Comment: Tested it on my CentOS box and array1 became an array. The OPs post did not include spaces or special characters. And, my post is meant to be informative, not an actual script. The OP is a new contributor and clearly just learning Bash.